# pyowm: Ошибка: 'Weather' object is not callable

Tags: python, telebot, pyowm

Попытался написать телеграм бота, который писал бы про погоду в каком-либо городе. Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 427,
in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 451,
in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in r
aise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in ru
n
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 12, in weatherzz
    w = observation.weather()
TypeError: 'Weather' object is not callable
```

Пробовал:

- pip3 uninstall telebot, pip3 install pytelegrambotapi.

Мой код:

```
from pyowm import OWM
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
owm = OWM('token')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def weatherzz(message):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather()
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
    answer = "Weather Status: ", w.detailed_status()
    answer += "Temperature: " + str(temp)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь впредь давать вопросам более конкретные заголовки.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас ошибки в этой части кода:

```py
w = observation.weather
temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
answer = f'Weather Status: {w.detailed_status}\n'
answer += f'Temperature: {temp}'
```

1. `observation.weather` — это атрибут класса `Observation` (не метод)
2. `w.detailed_status` — это атрибут класса `Weather` (не метод)
3. `answer` у Вас является кортежем

   Используйте для формирования ответа формат-строки или соответствующий метод.

Answer (score 1):

`observation.weather` это не функция, скобки лишние:

```
w = observation.weather
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Теперь всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `observation.weather()` попробуйте использовать эти две команды:

```
w = observation.weather
w.wind()
```